# How to prepare post request in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I have to send post request in python for following data

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}"
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac"
--data-binary "@audio-file1.flac"
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?timestamps=true&word_alternatives_threshold=0.9&keywords=%22colorado%22%2C%22tornado%22%2C%22tornadoes%22&keywords_threshold=0.5"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, for example reading http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by reading the documentation for [`post requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

This will send a similar request to your `curl` command:

```
import requests

url = 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/.......'
auth = ('{username}', '{password}')
headers = {'Content-type': 'audio/flac'}

with open('audio-file1.flac', 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post(url, auth=auth, headers=headers, data=f)
```

Some of the headers will differ, e.g. `User-Agent`, but otherwise the request is the same.

Instead of manually placing and escaping the query parameters in the query string you can instead use a dictionary and pass that to `requests.post()`:

```
url = 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize'
params = {
    'keywords': '"colorado","tornado","tornadoes"',
    'keywords_threshold': '0.5',
    'timestamps': 'true',
    'word_alternatives_threshold': '0.9'
}

with open('audio-file1.flac', 'rb') as f:
    r = request.post(url, params=params, auth=auth, headers=headers, data=f)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, here I have to read the remote file when I tried open() but it generates an error like 'there is no directory or file audio-file1.flac'.

Comment: @OmkarSingh: run the script in the same directory that contains the `audio-file1.flac` file. Otherwise edit the first argument of `open()` to include the path to the file.